# What are the Routh Hurwtiz Criteria for 3$\times$3 Matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling

The Criteria I know (for dynamical systems) is...

The eigenvalues of a matrix are guaranteed to be negative if Tr($J$)<0 and det($J$)>0, where $J$ is the Jacobian of some 2 dimensional dynamical system.  Are there equivalent criteria for 3 by 3 matrices?